# Setting vector<double> as choice values of wxComboBox

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am creating my first C++ program with GUI. 
I am using Code::Blocks v16.01 and wxWidgets v3.03.
I have found that in the wxComboBox class constructor, the type that stands for choices is wxArrayString. I have tried to convert vector  to vector and later to vector  and to wxArrayString, but it failed miserably...

My question is how to set default choice values of wxComboBox object?
Preferably I would like them to be filled with values of vector, created during program execution.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

vector <double> vector_double;
vector <string> vector_string;
vector <wxString> vector_wxstring;

void convert_double_to_string(vector<double> &dbl, vector <string> &str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dbl.size(); i++)
    {
        ostringstream stream;
        stream << dbl[i];
        str.push_back(stream.str());
    }
}
void convert_string_to_wxString(vector<string> & str, vector <wxString> &wxstr);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        wxstr.push_back(_(str[i]));
    }
}
void main()
{
    /////////

    // here setting vector_double's values

    //////////

   convert_double_to_string(vector_double, vector_string);
   convert_string_to_wxString(vector<string> vector_string, vector_wxstring);
}
```

This is what I have got. The string conversion to wxString is not working though. And even if it would, I wouldn't know how to insert it into wxArrayString.

Comment: You will obviously need to convert each of your double values to a string, then put those strings into a `wxArrayString`. Can you post your best attempt at that so we can see where you're having trouble?

Comment: @ChrisW., please show some code of what you tried and what went wrong - either you got a compiler/linker error or the program didn't do what you expected. Be as precise as possible.

Comment: This line is wrong: convert_string_to_wxString(vector<string> vector_string, vector_wxstring);  Remove the 'vector<string> '

Comment: Thank you @ravenspoint , it compiled succesfully!
I am able to set value of the wxComboBox, by using
ComboBox1->SetValue(vector_wxstring[1]);
However I still don't know how to set all the other possible choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
wxComboBox * cbo = new wxComboBox( ... );
wxArrayString as;
for ( auto& s : vector_string )
  as.Add( s );
cbo->Set( as );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. It turned out that conversion for vector <wxString> was unnecessary.